# Removing a command from DiscordBot CommandService

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I am trying to figure out how to remove a command from the discord bot after it has been created.  Here is how I create the command:

```
_commandService.CreateCommand("create").Parameter("message", ParameterType.Multiple).Do(async e =>
{        
    var message = e.Args.Skip(1).Aggregate("", (current, t) => current + (t + " "));;

    _commandService.CreateCommand("hello").Do(async cc =>
    {
        await e.User.SendMessage(customCommand.Message);
    });
});
```

The _commandService object is of type `Discord.Commands.CommandService`

Now, I want to be able to run:

```
_commandService.CreateCommand("delete").Parameter("message", ParameterType.Multiple).Do(async e =>
{    
    _commandService.DeleteCommand("hello");
});
```

However, no such method exists, nor am I able to access the commands inside _commandService object as everything is read only `get;`

Does anyone know how I can delete the command without having to restart the bot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible, but as of discord.net 1.0 you need to use the Modules system to do it. Unfortunately, it greatly complicates things. Hopefully they'll add a proper `DeleteCommand(string commandName)` in a future update.

**Why you need to do this** (this section not needed if you don't care about the discord.net source): The 
 class CommandMap (it stores the commands, unsurprisingly) exposes a method RemoveCommand that does what you're looking to do. The only reference to an object of this class in the source is in the private method RemoveModuleInternal in CommandService. This is exposed in one of two public methods: `RemoveModuleAsync(ModuleInfo module)` or `RemoveModuleAsync<T>()`. There is no other way to affect commands as of the 1.0 release.

**How to do it**: Get the ModuleInfo object for your module first. Preferably, the module you create will only contain the command you want to delete for reasons that should be obvious pretty soon. When you use `CreateModuleAsync(string primaryAlias, Action<ModuleBuilder> buildFunc)` (or one of the other methods used to add modules) you'll get the ModuleInfo object back. This does mean you need to use a ModuleBuilder instead of the simple `commandService.CreateCommand` method you use. Read up on how to do that [here](https://discord.foxbot.me/docs/guides/commands.html#with-attributes)... if the process still confuses you, it's an excellent topic for another question.

You need to keep track of the ModuleInfo object that CreateModuleAsync returns in some manner (the method I would use is below) and then your second command becomes:

```
// private ModuleInfo createInfo
_commandService.CreateCommand("delete").Parameter("message", ParameterType.Multiple).Do(async e =>
{    
    if (createInfo != null)
    {
        await _commandService.DeleteModuleAsync(createInfo);
    }
});
```

Do note that the entire module instance is getting deleted... that's why your "create" command should be the only thing in it.

**An alternate solution** (although significantly less elegant) if this whole Module business seems too complicated would be to store a boolean and simply toggle it to simulate the deletion of the command. That is:

```
// bool createNotDeleted = true;
_commandService.CreateCommand("create").Parameter("message", ParameterType.Multiple).Do(async e =>
{    
    if (createNotDeleted) 
    {
        var message = e.Args.Skip(1).Aggregate("", (current, t) => current + (t + " "));;

        _commandService.CreateCommand("hello").Do(async cc =>
        {
            await e.User.SendMessage(customCommand.Message);
        });
    }
    else
    {
        // error handling
    }    

});
```

and

```
_commandService.CreateCommand("delete").Parameter("message", ParameterType.Multiple).Do(async e =>
{    
    if (createNotDeleted)
    {
        createNotDeleted = false
        // return something indicating command is deleted
    }
    else
    {
        // error handling
    }
});
```